# failed to reset root password for gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I installed gitlab on a VM.  I was able to reset the root password after the initial install.  After that, I was unable to log back on (I was probably typing the wrong password and got locked out).  I reset the password using the gitlab console:

```
sudo gitlab-rails console production    
user = User.where(id: 1).first
user.password = 'secret_pass'
user.password_confirmation = 'secret_pass'
user.save!
```

I specified my new password in place of 'secret password'.  I did not see any errors on the console.  However, I am still unable to logon as root.  Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot/fix this issue? 
Thanks

**user info from command prompt**

```
   #<User id: 1, email: "xxx@hotmail.com", 
encrypted_password:"$2a$10$EUlyzuDG77Ux1uFyBJ6GNOydZsCGljb77eqmy7yVlvt..., reset_password_token: nil, 
reset_password_sent_at: nil, 
remember_created_at: nil, 
sign_in_count: 2, 
current_sign_in_at: "2015-11-28 19:30:26", 
last_sign_in_at: "2015-11-28 19:29:39", 
current_sign_in_ip: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 
last_sign_in_ip: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 
created_at: "2015-11-28 19:19:26", updated_at: "2015-11-28 23:42:59", name: "Administrator", 
admin: true, 
projects_limit: 10000, 
skype: "", 
linkedin: "", 
twitter: "", 
authentication_token: "7sx3z9waLg28vnssoTe1", 
theme_id: 2, 
bio: nil, 
failed_attempts: 0, 
locked_at: nil, 
username: "root", 
can_create_group: true, 
can_create_team: false, 
state: "active", 
color_scheme_id: 1, 
notification_level: 1, 
password_expires_at: nil, 
created_by_id: nil, 
last_credential_check_at: nil, 
avatar: nil, 
confirmation_token: "kdzR4DZ9jb5CsvRkx_7K", 
confirmed_at: "2015-11-28 19:19:27", 
confirmation_sent_at: "2015-11-28 19:19:27", 
unconfirmed_email: nil, 
hide_no_ssh_key: false, 
website_url: "", 
notification_email: "xxx@hotmail.com", 
hide_no_password: false, 
password_automatically_set: false, 
location: nil, 
encrypted_otp_secret: nil, 
encrypted_otp_secret_iv: nil, 
encrypted_otp_secret_salt: nil, 
otp_required_for_login: false, 
otp_backup_codes: nil, 
public_email: "", 
dashboard: 0, 
project_view: 0, 
consumed_timestep: nil, 
layout: 0>
```

Comment: Did you exit the console *before* trying to log on as root?

Comment: yes - it just does not work.  I have wasted way too much time on this.  Thinking of seeding it again or just dropping it altogether

Comment: I have tried using both the 'root' username as well as the email ID I attached to it.  Neither works with the modified password.  I have to wonder if the username logic relies on the domain name at all somehow.

Comment: Any chance you could *print* `User.where(id: 1).first`: that would give the username to use here.

Comment: adding it to the original note - on a side note, I am really betting on the fact that you'll figure it out.  You helped me with another gitolite question a few years ago

Comment: also, I did not setup postfix - I guess its mandatory if I want to add new users unless I misunderstood the process

Comment: @VonC thinking of trying sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:setup RAILS_ENV=production to reset - any thoughts?

Comment: I prefer to use a docker image of GitLab (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/tree/master/docker) That way, I know I can restart a container in a known state.

Comment: so far - my recommendation would be to avoid using gitlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the DNS setup for the server but that was not clear by the error message in the browser nor any of the logs I checked for gitlab.